# stay add to cart popup on product page

Tags: shopify

SHOPIFY: I want to stay popup until user input.

Single product page: When clicking on Add to cart, then it open Popup like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgs5J.png

I don't want to close this popup until user input.

I tried some code but it is not working.

```
Shopify.getCart();
    $(".nav-cart" ).addClass("pulsate");

    setTimeout(function(){$('.nav-cart').removeClass('pulsate');}, 500000);
```